# Travis CI: “UnCSS: Configuration missed” en Travis CI

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy probando [uncss-brunch](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch) con Travis en un [proyecto de prueba](https://github.com/arturocastro/quacknote). `brunch build` funciona localmente, pero cuando hago `git push` el build en Travis falla:

```
18 Apr 22:38:59 - error: UnCSS: Configuration missed.
```

Alguna idea de qué puede estar mal configurado o cómo podría obtener más información para encontrar el bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que no has configurado las opciones de UnCSS en tu archivo `brunch-config.js`.

El motivo por el que funciona con `brunch build` es que UnCSS no se está ejecutando realmente, solo corre cuando haces un *build* optimizado.  El script que utiliza Travis es, según veo en [el log](https://travis-ci.org/arturocastro/quacknote/builds/124046352), `"dist"` y que ha sido definido como: `"dist": "del public && npm test && brunch build -p"`.  Fíjate que en ese script le estás pasando el flag `-p` al final, lo que indica que debe ejecutar el *build* de producción u optimizado.

Para solucionar el problema, agrega a tu configuración de brunch la sección de UnCSS dentro de `plugins`, por ejemplo:

```
// Estos son valores de ejemplo, tienes que configurarlo según la estructura de tu proyecto
plugins: {
    // ...
    uncss: {
        options: {
            csspath: '../styles',
            htmlroot: 'build'
        },
        files: ['index.html', 'about.html']
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me he basado en [este issue](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch/issues/1) como ayuda adicional.